# Make devise paths unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

How can i make devise paths unavailable. Now i have all forms for registration, authorization and password restore on one page.

Here are my routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords", :registrations => "registrations" }, :path => 'accounts', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_up => 'new', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

so if i enter something like `accounts/new` in url, i will get to devise sign up page. Is it possible to make all devise pages unavailable? I should get `RoutingError` or `MissingTemplate` for example if i enter either of the devise routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just skip the parts you don't want:

```
devise_for :users,
  :controllers => {
    :passwords => "passwords",
    :registrations => "registrations" },
  :path => 'accounts',
  :path_names => { 
    :sign_in => 'login',
    :sign_up => 'new', 
    :sign_out => 'logout'},
  :skip => [:passwords, :registrations, :sessions]
```

Comment: That's it. Finally i skipped these controllers and added only `post` `put` and `delete` routes. Thanks